# Search a string between two timestamps starting from bottom of log file

Tags: bash, shell, search, sed, grep

I was trying to search for string `'Cannot proceed: the database is empty'` in file out.log from bottom to top only (as log file is quite huge and everyday it appends the log at last only) during time-stamps yesterday 10:30 pm to today 00:30 am only.

**Extract from out.log is as below:**

```
[Thu Jun  5 07:56:17 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1019022)
Writing Database Mapping For [data]

[Thu Jun  5 07:56:18 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1250008)
Setting Outline Paging Cachesize To [8192KB]

[Thu Jun  5 07:56:18 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013202)
Cannot proceed: the database is empty 

[Thu Jun  5 07:56:20 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013205)
Received Command [Load Database]

[Thu Jun  5 07:56:21 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1019018)
Writing Parameters For Database
```

I searched on google and SO and explored commands like `sed` and `grep` but unfortunately it seems like `grep` doesn't parse timestamps and `sed` prints all lines between two patterns.

Can anybody please let me know how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Try using `tac` to `cat` the logfile backwards :-)

Comment: could you pleasse give those infos: 1) idea of file size (100 Mb, 10 Gb, ...) sed could be slow if 4.000.000 line are to treat but it's peanuts with 10.000 lines 2) the log is for wich time scope (1 line is 3 month old or 24h on biggest log) ? 3) can we assume there are alwaways at least 1 event per hour (not necessary the cannot proceed ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of date comparison in awk:

```
tac file | awk '/Cannot proceed: the database is empty/ {f=$0; next} f{if (($3==5 && $4>"22:30:00") || ($4==6 && $4<="00:30:00")) {print; print f} f=""}'
```

#### Test

For this given file:

```
$ cat a
[Thu Jun  5 07:56:17 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1019022)
Writing Database Mapping For [data]

[Thu Jun  5 07:56:18 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1250008)
Setting Outline Paging Cachesize To [8192KB]

[Thu Jun  5 07:56:18 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013202)
Cannot proceed: the database is empty 

[Thu Jun  5 07:56:20 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013205)
Received Command [Load Database]

[Thu Jun  5 07:56:21 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1019018)
Writing Parameters For Database 

[Thu Jun  5 23:56:20 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013205)
Writing Parameters For Database 

[Thu Jun  5 23:56:20 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013205)
Cannot proceed: the database is empty 

[Thu Jun  5 22:56:21 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1019018)
Cannot proceed: the database is empty
```

It returns:

```
$ tac a | awk '/Cannot proceed: the database is empty/ {f=$0; next} f{if (($3==5 && $4>"22:30:00") || ($4==6 && $4<="00:30:00")) {print; print f} f=""}'
[Thu Jun  5 22:56:21 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1019018)
Cannot proceed: the database is empty 
[Thu Jun  5 23:56:20 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013205)
Cannot proceed: the database is empty
```

Comment: @fedorqui..but I need to run it as a scheduled job everyday so how I can generalize it for any `yesterday 10:30 pm to today 00:30 am` to run it everyday as a scheduled job ?

Comment: Well you can make use of a bash variable, such as `today=$(date "+%d")` and pass it to awk with `awk -v today=$(date "+%d") ... $3==today` etc.

Comment: thanks fedorqui..modified as per your suggestion and that worked.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the line with this:

```
awk '/Cannot proceed: the database is empty/{ts = last; msg = $0; next}; {last = $0}; END{if (ts) printf "%s\n%s\n", ts, msg}' log
```

Output:

```
[Thu Jun  5 07:56:18 2014]Local/data///47480280486528/Info(1013202)
Cannot proceed: the database is empty
```

It should be easy to refine the code depending on which part is really needed.

Comment: @konsolebox...I think it doesn't consider the timestamps window ? I need the error message foung only during any `yesterday 10:30 pm to today 00:30 am` sothat it can be run as a scheduled job.

Comment: @Sunny I see. My script only extracts the last one.

Comment: stil deserves +1... :-)